# problem Kernel panic - not syncing: fatal exception in interrupt drm_kms_helper:

Tags: wireless, kernel

I'm having a problem with my *Dell Inspiron 1564*,

I am getting this error:

```
problem Kernel panic - not syncing: fatal exception in interrupt drm_kms_helper:: panic occurred, switching back to text console
```

I've found that it is probably due to the *Broadcomm STA wireless driver*.

But I am not sure how to solve the issue, does anyone know what I should do/try ?

Comment: this has nothing to do with wireless driver. drm_kms_helper is part of the Linux GPU DRM driver. so apparently it has something to with your GPU. Nvidia, AMD ? proprietary or open source driver? kernel version? more info is needed here.

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like this bug: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/36539
Which kernel version are you running?

Comment: [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/471012/ubuntu-14-04-lts-fails-to-start-with-a-kernel-panic/482541#482541

I think you should take a look at this..

Comment: same problem here http://askubuntu.com/questions/471012/ubuntu-14-04-lts-fails-to-start-with-a-kernel-panic?lq=1

Comment: This seems like using an older kernel with a more modern KMS setting display driver. My suggestion would be to bring your kernel and driver closer together, such as installing a new kernel, using an older driver, or updating to a newer version of Ubuntu would will default to both.