# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS fails to start with a kernel panic

Tags: boot, kernel

[image]These errors occur while starting Ubuntu. I am dual booting Windows 8.1 with Ubuntu.

kernel panic - not syncing : fatal exception in interrupt.
shutting down cpus with NMI
drm_kms_helper : panic occurred, switching back to text console.

Nothing happens and Ubuntu freezes.

Comment: Did it work before? If so, which Ubuntu version was it?

Comment: I have used 12.04, 12.10, 13.04, 13.10 and now 14.04. Every version worked fine. Until 14.04 showed this error and froze. It has been installed since the day it was released. It showed this error on May 23, the day i posted this question.

Comment: What caused it? Did you install any kernel modules or updates?

Comment: Nothing I am aware of. Mostly I install through software updater. So I don't remember which update caused it.

Comment: In GRUB menu, select **Advanced options for Ubuntu**, choose older kernel (not recovery mode) and tell me if it works.

Comment: yup...it was a kernel problem. I removed the new kernel. Thanks...!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was probably caused by fixes and features backported from newer kernels.

In GRUB menu, select **Advanced options for Ubuntu**, choose the last kernel that worked (not recovery mode).

Now you can:

- Remove new kernel and keep using old one, **making your system vulnerable to old kernel exploits**
- Install newer kernel, for which these fixes were made

Easiest way to install new kernel is to download it from [kernel.ubuntu.com](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) and install it using `dpkg`.

First, select the version you want (preferably the newest non-rc one, `utopic` kernels will work for 14.04 too), then download 3 files:

- linux-headers-x.xx.x-xxxxxx-generic_x.xx.x-xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx_*architecture*.deb
- linux-headers-x.xx.x-xxxxxx_x.xx.x-xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx_all.deb
- linux-image-x.xx.x-xxxxxx-generic_x.xx.x-xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx_*architecture*.deb

Replace *architecture* with **i386** if you use 32-bit Ubuntu, or **amd64** if you use 64-bit one (**it has nothing to do with CPU manufacturer!**).

Move these files to separate directory, open your terminal, `cd` to that directory and then run this command:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

When `dpkg` finishes, you can reboot, and ensure that you are running the kernel you've installed:

```
uname -a
Linux m132 x.xx.x #1 SMP Tue Jun 10 00:45:23 CEST 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Remember, you'll have to update kernel manually now, because Software Updates will only install 3.13 patches, as the kernel version never changes after Ubuntu release.

If it still doesn't work, uninstall the kernel you've installed with

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-3.13.0-24 linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic
```

Replace 3.13.0-24 with version you want to uninstall (or press <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to list installed ones). Second command may throw an error as there's no `linux-image-extra` for some kernels.

PS: **Please**, follow [these instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Bugs) to make a bug report for that faulty kernel, so they can fix it for others :)