# Ubuntu not loading - kernel panic

Tags: kernel

Installed Ubuntu on new laptop with Win8.1 installed from USB key.
Worked fine and could dual boot.
Installed updates and rebooted when instructed
Got following message when booting into ubuntu:

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: fatal exception in interrupt
drm_kms_helper: panic occured, switching back to text console
```

(does not switch back and just hangs)
Reinstalled ubuntu but exact same happened although new version was installed on new partitions
Windows 8.1 loads fine
How do I fix?

Comment: If you can get to the grub prompt, hit `e` to edit the Ubuntu option and add "nomodeset" after `quiet splash`. Then F10 to boot. If that works, let us know and we'll update with how to make the change permanent.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04 LTS fails to start with a kernel panic](http://askubuntu.com/questions/471012/ubuntu-14-04-lts-fails-to-start-with-a-kernel-panic)

Answer (score -2):

I have  felt exactly the same problem. If windows 8.1 (or any operating system along which you wish to run ubuntu) recovery is available, than try installing ubuntu as the only operating system for your  laptop.

Comment: @darkenergy Are you saying that it being a dual-boot system is the cause of this kernel panic? If so, I recommend expanding your answer (by editing) to explain why you think this is the case.

Comment: @Eliah i have already felt the same problem twice. and i resolve this by installing ubuntu without dual-boot. also another reason for this kernel panic is when your linux-swap is too low, i am sorry i was forgot to wrote about this(linux-kernel) in my answer.